# Evento change só é disparado ao mudar aba ou mudar de janela

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocompletar, javascript-eventos

Boa tarde pessoal.

Estou tentando implementar um autocomplete utilizando o typeahead.js. Atribui um evento de change ao meu input para fazer uma requisição ajax que me traz os dados que serão exibidos na lista.

Porém, quando a tela é carregada e eu digito alguma coisa o meu evento não é disparado. Se eu tirar o foco do componente e digitar novamente o evento também não é disparado. Ele é disparado somente quando eu clico na barra de endereços, ou mudo de aba no navegador ou de janela. Após o evento ser disparado pela primeira vez, toda vez que digito alguma coisa o evento é disparado normalmente. Alguma ideia do porque isso pode estar acontecendo?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <script type='text/javascript'>
       $(function(){
          $("#nome").change(function(){
             var input = $(this).val()
             $.ajax({
               url: "loadNameChoices",
               type: "get",
               data:{input:input},
               contentType: 'application/json',
               success: function(response) {
                  $("#nome").typeahead({source:response});
               },
            });
         });
       });
   </script>
</head>

<body>
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
         <g:form name="formBusca" class="form-inline">
            <div class="panel-body">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Nome:</label>
                  <g:textField id="nome" name="nome" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"/>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Usuário:</label>
                  <g:textField  id="username" name="username" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"/>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
               <div class="text-right">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="search-button">Pesquisar</button>
                  <g:link action="form" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Novo</g:link>
               </div>
            </div>
         </g:form>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

O Backend da aplicação está sendo fendo com Grails, mas não acredito que isso tenha alguma relação.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O evento `change` em uma `input`, pode, por vezes, causar esse tipo de problema. Olhe esse exemplo:

```js
$('input').change(function(){
 $('span').text(this.value)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<span></span>
```

Veja que o texto no `span` não aparece ao ser digitado e sim em um `blur`, por isso o fato de ser disparado ao mudar a aba ou janela. Caso queira mudar isso pode usar vários outros eventos, como o `input`:

```js
$('input').on('input', function(){
 $('span').text(this.value)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<span></span>
```

Outros eventos: `keyup`, `keydown` e `keypress`.

No seu caso ficaria assism:

```
$(function() {
  $("#nome").on('input', function() {
    var input = $(this).val()
    $.ajax({
      url: "loadNameChoices",
      type: "get",
      data: {
        input: input
      },
      contentType: 'application/json',
      success: function(response) {
        $("#nome").typeahead({
          source: response
        });
      },
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Ótima resposta. Obrigado!!